# Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output

Tags: errors, minted, pygments, missing

I installed minted today as well as Python and Pygments, which I can run from the cmd. When I try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world"); 
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

> ! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
>   probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need the
>   outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
>   or may be using frozencache with a missing file.
>
> See the minted package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>   ...
>   \end{minted}

The other threads didn't help me and neither did Google. How do I solve this problem? I have set my option in pdfLatex to:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %filename.tex
```

Here is my [log file](https://pastebin.com/Zvgsza65).

My PATH is set so I can execute Python and pygmentize from the cmd without errors, and I can load the package as well. When it comes to using the minted package is when I receive the error.

Comment: what pdflatex commandline did you use (in particular did you use `-output-directory` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, thank you for the swift reply. The command line I used is 

    `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`

Comment: I just tried that exact command and your file worked for me. can you show the full log file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will try and upload the log file, as it is too long for me to post.

EDIT: I hope this [link](https://pastebin.com/Zvgsza65) works.

Comment: sorry i can't help, it looks reasonable to me (apart from the error) the actual calls (windows command line from miktex) are a bit different to mine, as I do not use miktex, but look quite plausible. I think you will need someone with a successful run on miktex to compare logs.

Comment: For those that get this error message when typesetting via Texpad, try including `minted` via `\usepackage[cache=false,outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}`. If you're not a Texpad user, `\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}` might help. These answers originate from this Github issue: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/81

Comment: For me the problem was that for some reason I didn't have sufficient permissions to run pygmentize. My solution was to go to change the permission settings of `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pygmentize.exe` so that anyone has the permission to run it.

Comment: For me, the reason it wasn't working was that I wasn't using `--shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 4):

For me this was due to two seperate problems: I didn't have enough privileges to run pygmentize, and I specified an `-aux-directory` argument to pdflatex without telling minted to look for the output file there. I had to fix both problems for it to work.

### Insufficient privileges to run pygmentize

One of the problems was that for some reason I didn't have sufficient permissions to run pygmentize. To solve this on Windows, follow these steps:

1. Go to the folder containing `pygmentize.exe` in Windows Explorer (for me it's `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pygmentize.exe`). If you don't know what folder that is, you can find it by running `where pygmentize.exe` in cmd.exe (if that command gives you an error you need to set up pygmentize as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1382840/513819)).
2. Right click on `pygmentize.exe`, then click on Properties > Security > Advanced > Continue:

   [image]

   (Sorry that it's in Swedish, but the buttons should be in the same place in any language. "Säkerhet" means "Security", "Avancerat" means "Advanced" and "Fortsätt" means "Continue".)
3. Next, click on Add > Choose a main account:

   [image]

   ("Lägg till" means "Add", "Välj ett huvudkonto" means "Choose a main account")
4. In the text box, type "Users" in your system language (so if your system is in English type "Users", if it's in Swedish type "Användare", if it's in French type "Utilisateurs", etc). Then click on "Control Name", then "OK".

   If it complains that what you typed is invalid, you can go to Advanced > Search Now to see a list of valid options, there should be something in there that means "Users". Alternatively, if you only need it to work for your user account, you can also type your Windows username.
5. Check the checkboxes "Read" and "Read and Execute", and make sure "Allow" is selected under "Type":

   [image]

   ("Läsa" means "read", "köra" means "execute", "Typ" means "Type" and "Tillåt" means "Allow")
6. Click OK on each window you've opened.

### `-aux-directory` in pdflatex

If you've specified an `-aux-directory` argument to pdflatex (which you can do in TeXstudio by going to Settings > Configure TeXstudio > Commands > PdfLaTeX), you need to explicitly specify that as `ouptupdir` to the minted package. For example, I use `-aux-directory=C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp`, so I needed to do `\usepackage[outputdir=C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp]{minted}` insead of just `\usepackage{minted}`.

In general the `outputdir` should be the one where Latex puts auxiliary files, in this case the file that's interesting is the `.pygtex` file. If you haven't specified an `-aux-directory` the default should be your current working directory in both cases so you shouldn't need to do anything, but if it still doesn't work you might need to search for where it put the `.pygtex` file and specify that as `outputdir`.

Comment: Using an auxdir is almost never a good idea. You'll run into so many strange problems.

Comment: The OP explicitly says that they can run pygmentize "My PATH is set so I can execute Python and pygmentize from the cmd without errors, " so while changing the pygmentize settings may have solved your problem, it is not an answer to the question asked

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even if it's not helpful to the OP, it might be helpful to other who find this question through Google. The purpose of Stack Exchange is to help future readers, not just the OP.

Comment: yes but helpfully answering a different question doesn't really fit the format. If the question is how to set up tex to call an installed pygments. An answer on how to install pygments is obviously related but not really an answer. Does no harm though, I would not have commented except for the fact that you asked in meta why the question was closed and the reason was it was not reproducible and had no answer as posted.

Comment: Using the `outputdir` option in `minted` also works for `output-directory` in `latexmk`

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are working fine for me, I've tried the following commands I used the `DOS` prompt to get the output, hope `--shell-escape` is the solution for your problem, but not sure, please try at your end:

`latex --shell-escape %filename.tex` to get the output as in DVI format

`pdflatex --shell-escape %filename.tex`  to get the output as in PDF format

and the output was generated as:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried your proposed solution, but unfortunately it gave me the same error. Perhaps there is something wrong with my PATH environment or my directory? Unfortunately, I am not tech savy enough to know this. I probably forgot something crucial and/or obvious.

Comment: Can you tell me what release of LaTeX you are using? I am using MikTeX version 2.9 in Windows OS...

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9.6 and TexMaker 5.0

Comment: `-shell-escape` does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had properly used `-shell-escape` and installed `Pygments`. I was still getting the error.

The reason was I was using `\begin{minted}{txt}` and not `\begin{minted}{text}`.

Make sure you are using a [Pygments supported language](https://pygments.org/languages/). (There is only a short name entry for `text` not `txt`.)

Comment: That's not it. I'm using `-shell-escape` and the problem is still there.

Comment: That's not it. You did not read this answer.