# Problem using minted option from tcbuselibrary

Tags: errors, tcolorbox, minted, missing, pygments

I'm still a newbie using LaTeX and I need to add a line of code in my document. For this, I use the library `listings` from the package `tcolorbox`. I always get the same error, so I put this example from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174455/typeset-source-code-with-tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
    colframe=cyan,
    colback=cyan!10,
    listing only,
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm},
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{mylisting}
        int main(int ac, char *av[]) 
        {
            printf("Hello, World");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{mylisting}
    
    \begin{mylisting}
        int main(int ac, char *av[], char **ep,char *av[], char **ep) 
        {
            printf("Hello, World");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{mylisting}
    
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code I get:

> Package minted Error: Cannot find Pygments style default. \end{mylisting}
> Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{mylisting}
> Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{mylisting}

I tried to check a similar issue. ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440511/package-minted-error-missing-pygments-output)), but I cannot solve it

I have set the option for PdfLaTeX

> pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex

I hope you can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need pygments installed. From the terminal type pygmetize -h to see if  you have it installed and in  your path as well. Are you on windows?

Comment: https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/

Comment: Thank you very much, dear yannisl. The problem was that I used Manim a while ago and I had two files pygments.exe in different paths, so I think that was the problem. Have a nice day

Comment: I dont remember offhand  where the pygments style files are installed, if you add custom styles then please read the pygments documentation for that.